# Conflict with classes names in css files

Tags: css

I need to integrate two projects based on HTML and raw CSS. I noticed conflict with classes name in css files.

I can change my files by hand but it seems to be not the best solution.
Can I do it automaticly?

I am using phpStorm, is there option for doing this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does "conflict with classes name" mean?

Comment: some classes from one file are overwrite from other and they are not read correctly

Comment: how many classes are conflicting exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about phpStorm, but all editors should have a "Find and Replace" option, you could use that to change all occurrences of your conflicting classe...

Answer (score 1):

If you have classes, from another file you can use the "Find and replace all" funcion, and change the names, that way you won't have to do it 100% manually, you can also place the "correct file" under the other css in HTML, and it will then use the "correct class" unless !important are used in the other css.